# Get RecyclerView Width

Tags: java, kotlin, android-recyclerview

My recyclerView width is currently set to Wrap_Parent. After the recyclerView is filled with data and drawn I want to to get the actual width and set a TextView width to match it.

Similar to "textView.width = recyclerView.width".

In this situation the textView is above my recyclerView as a label and I want them to match widths so it looks unform.

Where is the best location to put this code to get this to work ASAP after the recyclerView is drawn? I have tried so many things and the textView never changes.

- adapter - ViewHolder?
- adapter - onBindViewHolder?
- activity - onCreate()?
- activity - GET method response?

Comment: Can anyone help out here?